# The song playing in My Hero Academia season 3 episode 14 when everyone is training

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the name of the soundtrack in *My Hero Academia* season 3, episode 14 beginning at 18:45 when everyone is training?

Answer (score 0):

It's 英雄的武闘戦闘曲 (Heroic Fighting Battle Song), the 18th track from [*My Hero Academia 2nd Original Soundtrack*](https://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia_2nd_Original_Soundtrack).

[YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0uq6k0va6Y)